# Can we compare in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My question is about comparing in mapreduce.

Here I have a sample weather data

```
0067011990999991950051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9-04001+99999999999
0043011990999991950051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+04221+99999999999
0043011990999991950051518004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00261220001CN9999999N9+04111+99999999999
0043012650999991949032412004+62300+010750FM-12+048599999V0202701N00461220001CN0500001N9+01111+99999999999
0043012650999991949032418004+62300+010750FM-12+048599999V0202701N00461220001CN0500001N9+04781+99999999999
```

I am able to process and I got the result max temperature in a year.

**output:**

```
1901    46
1902    39
1910    46
1911    44
1915    48
1916    30
1949    47
1950    42
1960    35
1970    36
1980    35
1990    45
2000    46
```

Is it possible to compare the max temperature in the above mentioned years (from output of mapreduce we need to process)?

Please tell me all the possible ways of doing this.

I am confused, because here keys are unique and values are unique.

Answer (score 0):

don't get you,do you want to get the max value which is 48 in the output?

if yes, just write a mapper, define a variable max, iterate the output file, if find the value  bigger than max, just set it to max. then max is the max value.

Comment: My question is i got the output from mapreduce(i.e Year and max temperature) in that i would like to find the year with max temperature. i mean the output should be 1915  48

Comment: you just need to define another variable year, and every time you set the bigger temperature to max, also set the key which is the year to the variable year. and do this in the mapper cleanup method. you can check it in my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

code is as follows:

```
    private int maxYear = 0;
    private int maxTemperature = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] tokens = value.toString().trim().split(",");
    int year = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]);
    int temperature = Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]);
    if (temperature > maxTemperature) {
        maxTemperature = temperature;
        maxYear = year;
    }
}

@Override
protected void cleanup(Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("maxYear:" + maxYear + ",maxTemperature:" + maxTemperature);
    ctx.write(new IntWritable(maxYear), new IntWritable(maxTemperature));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Raj:
If I understand correctly, there's a dataset with you containing the temperature records for various years and you wrote a Mapper get the maximum temperature for each year. Now from this record, you want to write a reducer to get the maximum value?

You may wanna write your reducer something like this for comparison of values:

```
Text max = Values.next();
while(Values.hasNext()){
Text current = Values.next();
if(current.compareTo(max) > 0)
max = current;
}
output.collect(key, (Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text(max));
```

Hope this helps!

PS: I wrote this on Hadoop 2, you may wanna consider using of hadoop classes if you're using earlier version. Some might be deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a private static variable MAX in reducer class above your reduce function with an initial value. Then compare this MAX variable inside the reduce function against value pair you obtained until you have scanned all the key and value pairs. Once everything s done emit it as output Key.